# Is there any way to use the utl_file to generate a csv from data more than 32000 in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, utl-file

..
FILE1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR','cg.csv','w',32000);
.. 
we are generating a csv file which has concatenated value of many columns of a view. 
Is there any way to use the utl_file to generate a csv from data more than 32000 in oracle plsql

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
FILEHANDLE           UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
WRITEMESSAGE   varchar2(200);
longLine varchar2(32767);
newline char(2) :=  CHR(13) || CHR(10);
begin
longLine :=  LPAD('aaaa', 32766,'x');
FILEHANDLE        := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('XMLDIR','lonLineFile.txt','wb',32767);
for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (filehandle,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (longLine),true); 
  UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (filehandle,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (longLine),true); 
  UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (filehandle,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (longLine),true); 
  UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (filehandle,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (newline),true); 
end loop;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(filehandle);
end;
/
```

Open file in 'wb' write byte mode. Next write raw to file and end of line char.

Comment: UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (filehandle,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (longLine),true); this does the main work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1004618) for the function `UTL_FILE.FOPEN`:

> FOPEN max_linesize parameter must be a number in the range 1 and 32767

so you can increase it to 32767, but not further then that.

You might want to consider creating multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way - use `clob` data type instead of `varchar2`. `clob` [maximum size in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943) is 128TB.

In your PL/SQL code first collect data to a [temporary clob](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_creating.htm#ADLOB45640). Second iterate the clob in chunks and feed those to [`utl_file`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS069).

Below is a random internet code snippet that writes an arbitrary clob to a user defined file:

```
procedure save (
  p_text in clob,
  p_path in varchar2,
  p_filename in varchar2
) as
  v_lob_temp blob;
begin
  --
  -- exit if any parameter is null
  --
  if    p_text is null
     or p_path is null
     or p_filename is null then
    return;
  end if;

  --
  -- convert a clob to a blob
  --
  declare
    v_dest_offset pls_integer := 1;
    v_src_offset pls_integer := 1;
    v_lang_context pls_integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
    v_warning pls_integer := dbms_lob.no_warning;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => v_lob_temp,
                             cache => true,
                             dur => dbms_lob.call);

    dbms_lob.converttoblob(dest_lob => v_lob_temp,
                           src_clob => p_text,
                           amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
                           dest_offset => v_dest_offset,
                           src_offset => v_src_offset,
                           blob_csid => dbms_lob.default_csid,
                           lang_context => v_lang_context,
                           warning => v_warning);
    -- TODO raise (what?) when warning
  end;

  --
  -- write a blob to a file
  --
  declare
    v_lob_len pls_integer;
    v_fh utl_file.file_type;
    v_pos pls_integer := 1;
    v_buffer raw(32767);
    v_amount pls_integer := 32767;
  begin
    v_fh := utl_file.fopen(p_path, p_filename, 'wb', 32767);

    v_lob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_lob_temp);

    while v_pos < v_lob_len loop
      dbms_lob.read(v_lob_temp, v_amount, v_pos, v_buffer);

      utl_file.put_raw(file => v_fh,
                       buffer =>v_buffer,
                       autoflush => false);

      v_pos := v_pos + v_amount;
    end loop;

    utl_file.fclose(v_fh);
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_lob_temp);
  end;

end;
```